# C# MVC Datatype to pass for stored procedure output parameter

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a SQL server stored procedure from a C# MVC controller. The parameters for the stored procedure are as follows:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spVehicleSearch360]
    @strLocale          nvarchar(10),
    @xmlSearchCriteria  xml,
    @strSortBy          nvarchar(30),
    @strSortDir         nvarchar(5),
    @uidSessionId       uniqueidentifier,
    @iPage                int = 1,
    @iPageSize          int = 10,
    @iCount               int output,
    @iTotalCount        int output,
    @bShowResults       bit = 1,
    @xmlResults         xml = null output,
    @dtLastItemModified datetime = null output,
    @uidVehicleInList uniqueidentifier = null
as
begin 
.........
.........
.........
```

When I call this from my controller:

```
var search_results = db.spVehicleSearch(strLocale, xmlSearchCriteria, strSortBy, strSortDir, uidSessionId, iPage, iPageSize, iCount, iTotalCount, bShowResults, xmlResults, dtLastItemModified, uidVehicleInList);
```

I am getting the following error for the stored procedure's output parameters (arguments 8,9,11,12)

> Arugment [n]: cannot convert from [int/string/system.DateTime] to
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter'

What should I be passing in for these arguments?

(Apologies if this is a very elementary question, I am very new to .net)

Thank you

Comment: I assume you are using entity framework? What is the signature of `db.spVehicleSearch()` in your model?

Comment: You should be passing in variables with the same datatypes as you are expecting as output.

Comment: @SvenGrosen Here you go. It specifies ObjectParameter for the troublesome parameters but I'm unsure how to declare these before passing them in: public virtual int spVehicleSearch(string strLocale, string xmlSearchCriteria, string strSortBy, string strSortDir, Nullable<System.Guid> uidSessionId, Nullable<int> iPage, Nullable<int> iPageSize, ObjectParameter iCount, ObjectParameter iTotalCount, Nullable<bool> bShowResults, ObjectParameter xmlResults, ObjectParameter dtLastItemModified, Nullable<System.Guid> uidVehicleInList)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to address this is to just wrap the parameters that are declared as `ObjectParameter` in instances of that class, like this:

```
var iCountParam = new ObjectParameter("iCount", typeof(int));
var iTotalCountParam = new ObjectParameter("iTotalCount", typeof(int));
var xmlResultsParam = new ObjectParameter("xmlResults", typeof(string));
var dtLastItemModifiedParam = new ObjectParameter("dtLastItemModified", typeof(DateTime));

var search_results = db.spVehicleSearch(strLocale, xmlSearchCriteria, strSortBy, strSortDir, uidSessionId, iPage, iPageSize, iCountParam, iTotalCountParam, bShowResults, xmlResultsParam, dtLastItemModifiedParam, uidVehicleInList);
//using your previously declared variables...
iCount = (int)iCountParam.Value;
iTotalCount = (int)iTotalCountParam.Value;
//since these are nullable params, gotta check before casting
//you can obviously use whatever you want for the value if it is indeed null
xmlResults = Convert.IsDBNull(xmlResultsParam.Value) ? null : (string)xmlResultsParam.Value;
dtLastItemModified = Convert.IsDBNull(dtLastItemModifiedParam.Value) ? DateTime.MinValue : (DateTime)dtLastItemModifiedParam.Value;
```

Entity Framework has a hard time dealing with output parameters in this way, and wraps them in the generic `ObjectParameter` type to make things easier, although it means more boiler-plate code for you.